# Redirect Rule in htaccess for a folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress hosting site www.mysite.com/myBlog . The wordpress installation is done inside public_html/www/myBlog folder inside my host folder.

I also have a folder public_html/www/myName which redirects me to a domain myName.com

Although this works fine but inside myName folder i have files like index.html. acad.html, worexp.html

clicking on them i expect a behavior like

myName.com/index.html
myName.com/acad.html
myName.com/workex.html

though i get it as myname.com only.

I found htaccess rules in myName folder as :

```
Redirect http://mydomainName.com/myName/+ 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainName.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomainName\.com\/myBlog" [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help me with whats wrong with the htaccess file ?

More details:

My WordPress blog has something messed up. I can go to my blog and homepage works fine but when i try to go to any post it throws an 403 error. Apache forbidden.

1. Tried talking to web host for permissions its ok.
2. checked htaccess. Replaced code by default code stil not working.
3. Removed permalinks to default deleted htaccess created new permalinks.
4. Gave permissions to all the files in blog directory
5. Rewrote robots.txt Blog url is : www.windowsvj.com
6. Wordpress community is not able to suggest something very helpful too.

Current Redirect rule code in .htaccess is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /wpblog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wpblog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This question belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: how can i move the existing question to server fault ?

Comment: The question is too old to be migrated. You could copy+paste the question over there. But as a question cannot be close while it has an open bounty, you can simply wait a week whether you get a good answer here.

Comment: Is the last rule-set the only one in .htaccess or are there more rules? You mention there are posts so at some point the WP install was working, how was the .htaccess file content at that moment and why did it change?

Comment: @Faa yes it was working at one time and i have no clue when one of my changes broke the things. Last set of rewrite rules is most current one.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of **FollowSymLinks** being disabled in the server configuration. Simply adding `Options +FollowSymlinks` to the **.htaccess** file could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the flag [L]

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /wpblog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]      <---
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wpblog/index.php [L] <---
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Try using [QSA]

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /wpblog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [QSA]      <---
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wpblog/index.php [QSA] <---
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

How [L] works is if the RewriteRule matches

```
RewriteRule . /wpblog/index.php [L]
```

Then all other rewrites after this RewriteRule are ignored as stated on the Apache website

> *"In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed." http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html*

Here is a link with more information on .htaccess flags

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Hope this works for you :P